I don't understand why my rendering doesn't work
I did an animation in Blender. I first rendered it, it worked fine, but I wanted to do some adjustments so changed the animation. Now that I try to render it, it doesn't work.
Even if I try to render an image, it shows a new window opening, but nothing happens, like the image doesn't charge. And when I try to render my animation, it goes super quickly, and same doesn't show an image charging, it doesn't do frames by frames which is what I want, and when I open the render it's just a black image.
My render is set to Cycles, and I set up the render on png, with a file in my documents for the frames to go to. I really don't understand what's wrong.

Okay I found the problem ! so first go to compositing and check that you have a render layers, and that it's image is connected to the image of the composite. Then, if that doesn't work, go into the video sequencing panel in the compositing tab. My problem was that I had an image sequence (from my last animation) still in the video sequencing bit. Once I deleted it, my animation came out fine.
